# Convert from Simple Ray Casting to X-Ray Rendering

Tags: three.js, raycasting, volume-rendering, webgl2

I am referring to the code by [Lebarba](http://www.lebarba.com/) for Volume Rendering. What I am trying to do is the X-Ray Rendering rather than Ray casting.

Here is the result for the Ray casting with the code

**RayCasting**

```
             for(int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPS; i++)
               {
                //Get the voxel intensity value from the 3D texture.
                colorSample = sampleAs3DTexture( currentPosition );

                //Allow the alpha correction customization.
                alphaSample = colorSample.a * alphaCorrection;

                //Applying this effect to both the color and alpha accumulation results in more realistic transparency.
                alphaSample *= (1.0 - accumulatedAlpha);

                //Scaling alpha by the number of steps makes the final color invariant to the step size.
                alphaSample *= alphaScaleFactor;

                //Perform the composition.
                accumulatedColor += colorSample * alphaSample;

                //Store the alpha accumulated so far.
                accumulatedAlpha += alphaSample;

                //Advance the ray.
                currentPosition += deltaDirection;
                accumulatedLength += deltaDirectionLength;

                //If the length traversed is more than the ray length, or if the alpha accumulated reaches 1.0 then exit.
                if(accumulatedLength >= rayLength || accumulatedAlpha >= 1.0 )
                    break;
            }

            gl_FragColor  = accumulatedColor;

        }
```

[image]

And here is the code where I have made changes for X-ray mode rendering along with the image generated.
[image]

**X-Ray Mode**

```
     for(int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPS; i++)
            {
                //Get the voxel intensity value from the 3D texture.
                colorSample = sampleAs3DTexture( currentPosition );


            //console.log(colorSample);

                    //Allow the alpha correction customization.
                alphaSample = colorSample.a * alphaCorrection;

                //Applying this effect to both the color and alpha accumulation results in more realistic transparency.
                alphaSample *= (1.0 - accumulatedAlpha);

                //Scaling alpha by the number of steps makes the final color invariant to the step size.
                alphaSample *= alphaScaleFactor;

                //Perform the composition.
                //accumulatedColor += colorSample/float(887);
                accumulatedColor = accumulatedColor + colorSample/float(MAX_STEPS);

                //Store the alpha accumulated so far.
                accumulatedAlpha += alphaSample;

                //Advance the ray.
                currentPosition += deltaDirection;
                accumulatedLength += deltaDirectionLength;

                //If the length traversed is more than the ray length, or if the alpha accumulated reaches 1.0 then exit.
                if(accumulatedLength >= rayLength || accumulatedAlpha >= 1.0 )
                    break;
            }

            gl_FragColor  = accumulatedColor;
```

I am not sure what I am doing is right or wrong as I am new to this field.
It would be of great help if someone can point out the error if there is any.

Comment: Do a CT and you'll see if the result is correct immediately.